# Windows 10: cannot cd $ANDROID_HOME

Tags: windows-10, powershell, path

I have a user environment variable setup:

ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

[image]

In the Windows 10 Powershell, if I try: cd $ANDROID_HOME, I receive the following error:

[image]

```
cd : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is null. Change the value of argument "path" to a
non-null value.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd $ANDROID_HOME
```

Should it be possible to CD to an environment variable path?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Should it be possible to CD to an environment variable path?

PowerShell handles environment variables differently to `cmd`.

To display their values in PowerShell use the following syntax:

```
$Env:variablename
```

Example:

```
> echo %Path%
%Path%
> $Env:Path
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\apps\WSCC\Sysinternals Suite;C:\apps\WSCC\NirSoft Utilities
>
```

So, in your particular case, you need the following command in Powershell:

```
cd $Env:ANDROID_HOME
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of Windows PowerShell commands](http://ss64.com/ps/) - An excellent reference for all things PowerShell related.
- [Environment Variables](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-env.html)
- [Take Charge of Environment Variables in PowerShell](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/take-charge-environment-variables-powershell)